# Getting an issue on saving data through save() method in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm developing a web app using a cakephp. I've one function in which I want to save some data to the model using cakephp's save() method. But whenever I'm going to save the data I'm getting this kind of error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method App::save() in /httpdocs/MyApp/app/Controller/AppsController.php on line 71
```

Anyone know what I'm missing here. My controller's function is as below:

```
public function add_app($id=null){
    $this->layout = 'user';
    if (!empty($id)) {

        $this->request->data['App']['id_users'] = $_SESSION['edit_user_id'];
        $this->request->data['App']['id_store'] = $id;
        $this->request->data['App']['id_unique_app'] = $Guid;
        $this->request->data['App']['tx_app_name'] = $data['results'][0]['trackName'];
        $this->request->data['App']['tx_platform'] = 'iOS';
        $this->request->data['App']['nu_price'] = $data['results'][0]['price']; 
        $this->request->data['App']['da_created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        if ($this->App->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The selected app has been added successfully.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }

    }

}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if ($this->save($this->request->data))
```

instead of

```
if ($this->App->save($this->request->data))
```

Comment: @rikesh.. Is this possible to save data without specifying the model?

Comment: @amit - I hope kevin has explained you about the same :)

Answer (score 0):

what's your controller name ?

In CakePHP, the "App" controller will only be able to call "App" model.

if it's "App" controller, then you have to use

```
if ($this->save($this->request->data))
```

instead of

```
if ($this->App->save($this->request->data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$uses = array('ModelName');` at the top of your controller class.

Then you may use:

```
$this->ModelName->save($this->request->data);
```